# JavaScript: filtered data doesn't show on DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Ideally the code is to present some data on the webpage after submitting the form:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input id="label" type="text">
    <button id="label_btn" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="plate"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
const all_levels = [{"word": "花", "label": "は", "english": "flower"}, {"word": "八", "label": "は", "english": "eight"}, {"word": "七", "label": "な", "english": "seven"}, {"word": "六", "label": "ろ", "english": "six"}]

const label = document.querySelector('#label'),
      labelBtn = document.querySelector('#label_btn'),
      plate = document.querySelector('#plate');

labelBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let words = [];
    if (label.value == "") 
        words = all_levels;
    else {
        const inputValue = label.value.split(', ')
        for (input of inputValue) 
          words.push(...all_levels.filter(word => word.label == input))
        // console.log(words)
        return words;
    }

    plate.innerHTML = words.map(word => 
        `<p class="word">
            ${word.word}
            <span>${word.english}</span>
        </p>`
    ).join("");
});
```

Thanks for Andreas's suggestion that some problems were solved. What's remained is, although the words of multiple labels show correctly in the console, they don't on the webpage. I'd also tried below code which didn't work either:

```
else {
    words = all_levels.filter(word, i => {
      return this.keys.indexOf(i.word.label) > -1;
    }, {
      "keys" : ["は", "な"]
    }
}
```

PS. I can't get the last part of code... just took it from a similar question thread here.

Comment: For your first problem: change the type of the button to `type="button"`

Comment: @Andreas Hey, thanks! It does work!